# SQL Server Compact Edition and Repository Pattern

Tags: .net, repository, sql-server-ce

I would like use Repository Pattern and MS SQL Compact Edition in my project.
My question is which framework or technology do I use for it?

- Linq2Sql hasn't data provider for SQL CE
- SubSonic hasn't support for SQL CE
- NHibernate looks huge for this, I think.

I would like use my POCOs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sqlmetal.exe to build the Linq2Sql DBML file, then include it in your project.

http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/898/Using-LinqToSQL-with-SqlServer-Compact.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about the Entity Framework?  That works with the latest SQL CE.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx
http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/